# Change copy-paste VBA macro from line-by-line to batch copy-paste

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I currently have a VB macro that will copy-past values from one sheet to another. Currently however, the VB is written in a way that it will do it row-by-row and this runs pretty slow since it goes through a few thousand rows. I'm wondering how would be best to change my VB to do a batch copy-paste to cut down on waiting time. Code is:

```
Sub copypaste_settlement_rows()

Dim LastRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Settlement Template").Select
'find last row in column A
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To LastRow
    Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 42).Copy
    Sheets("PIVOT DATA").Select
    NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Sheets("Settlement Template").Select
Next x

Sheets(">> START HERE <<").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to select rows within the table with batch?

Answer (score 6):

This should be instantaneous and it does not use the clipboard:

```
Sub copypaste_settlement_rows()
    Dim v
    With Sheets("Settlement Template")
        v = .Cells(2, 1).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, 42)
    End With
    With Sheets("PIVOT DATA")
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Resize(UBound(v), UBound(v, 2)) = v
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry for the late response, I just got to testing this today. While it does work instantaneously, I ran into a few issues - namely that about 40% of the time it will proc a run time error 7 out of memory. It also seemed to skip the last line it was "copying" from the 'Settlement Template' sheet. I will play around with it a bit more but if I can get it to capture everything and stop erroring out this is definitely what I am looking for!

Answer (score 1):

An extremely simple way (and the fastest I've seen in my own code) is:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PIVOT DATA").Range("A2:A" & lastRow) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Settlement Template").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value
```

Comment: I will be testing this today and comparing with the above answer, thank you!